# How do I Serialize Object to Database for Hibernate to read in Java

Tags: java, database, hibernate, serialization

I'm currently writing a tool to plug into an existing enterprise application that uses Hibernate.  My tool at install time needs to write some values into the database where one of the columns is a serialized version of a setting descriptor object.  This object has two lists of objects and a few primitive types.

My current approach is to create a `ByteArrayOutputStream` and an `ObjectOutputStream` and then write the `ObjectOutputStream` to the `ByteArrayOutputStream`, then passing the resulting byte array into the sql with Spring's 1SimpleJdbcTemplate1.  My current issue with this approach is that when the enterprise tool pulls my rows it fails to de-serialze the column with the following:

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateSystemException: could not deserialize; nested exception is org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize
```

I feel I may need to serialize the inner objects, but have no clue how to do that and keep everything together.

Comment: This is very odd. Normally, that "serialized object" would be a foreign key to another table which hibernate manages. Why are you trying to shove an object into a database backed by hibernate in a very non-hibernate way?

Comment: This may be dumb, but this simple install class would be the only place I would need hibernate, and doing this with hibernate involves either including the enterprise application's framework jar or coping several classes into my project.  I was trying to avoid doing either of those to keep the tool as light and de-coupled from the enterprise application as possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ended up solving my own problem.  In the hibernate API there is a class called [SerializationHelper](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/api/org/hibernate/util/SerializationHelper.html) that has a static function `serialize(Serializable obj)` which I was able to use to serialize my object and then insert it into the database.  Hibernate was then able to read it in the enterprise app.

Answer (score 1):

You can serealize a Java object into bytes and then store it in a BLOB.

Serialize:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream byteOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream objOut = new ObjectOutputStream(byteOut);
objOut.writeObject(object);
objOut.close();
byteOut.close();
byte[] bytes = byteOut.toByteArray()
```

Deserialize:

```
 public <T extends Serializable> T getObject(Class<T> type) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
        if(bytes == null){
            return null;
        }
        ByteArrayInputStream byteIn = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(byteIn);
        T obj = (T) in.readObject();
        in.close();
        return obj;
    }
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm already doing and Hibernate is failing to de-serialize my object

Comment: Are you storing it as a byte[] with the @Lob annotation?