# Saving class instances in a database

Tags: java

If i have a person class having a two fields Name(String) and ID(integer), how can i save instances of this class in a database? Is it possible to define a new datatype Person? or do i need to save the fields one after the other in a database containing columns Name,ID?
And for the second case is the below code the appropriate way to do it?

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                         "jdbc:myDriver:myDatabase",
                         username,
                         password);
Person P1;

Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
stmt.execute("INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES ("+ P1.Name ", " + P1.ID ")");
```

Comment: how about serialization like this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5966039/how-do-i-serialize-object-to-database-for-hibernate-to-read-in-java?rq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, both fields must be saved in two separate columns.

And no, this is not the proper way to insert the values. Learn to use [prepared statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) to pass parameters when executing a query, and thus avoid problems with unescaped quotes and SQL injection attacks.

You should also always specify the column names instead of relying on their default order:

```
insert into person (id, name) values (?, ?)
```

Also, your code should respect the Java naming conventions, and shouldn't use public fields: `p1.getName()` rather than `P1.Name`.

Comment: Also you should follow java naming convention: variables and methods start with small letter, classes with capital letter. And also take a look on ORM.